# Decrypt p7s file on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, pkcs#7

Working on a test `iOS` app I have faced the following problem.

From a remote webserver I recieve a `.p7s` file with the following contents (which are viewable in Mac's `TextEdit` app):

```
0Ä  *ÜHÜ˜
†Ä0Ä10  +�0Ä    *ÜHÜ˜
†Ä$ÄÇ˚<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CHALLENGE</key>
    <string>panacya</string>
    <key>IMEI</key>
    <string>01 232700 828513 5</string>
    <key>PRODUCT</key>
    <string>iPad1,1</string>
    <key>SERIAL</key>
    <string>GB0269NJETU</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>2866681d94ae6c56d189485d39c54eaedecf211c</string>
    <key>VERSION</key>
    <string>9A5288d</string>
</dict>
</plist>
������†Ç
[0ÇÛ0Ç\†
u6ÜΩ~60
    *ÜHÜ˜
�0Z10   UUS10U

Apple Inc.10UApple iPhone10UApple iPhone Device CA0
110808222517Z
140808222517Z0ÅÉ1-0+U$2890C19C-43F9-47C5-8534-A54F184E37DC10    UUS10   UCA10U  Cupertino10U
```

Here's the link to the original file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/lm05gg866zdrz20/ota-response.p7s?dl=0

I then save the `NSData` as a `.p7s` file to disk.

I need to get the embedded `.plist` out of the file (judging from what I see it contains exactly that) or at least convert it to readable `NSString` which I can then display in `UILabel`.

Is it at all possible and how do I achieve it?

Comment: There is no decrypting, just extracting the plist from a data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it into an `NSData` instnace and use

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfData:(NSData *)dataToFind options:(NSDataSearchOptions)mask range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

to find the beginning and end of the plist. Then use

```
- (NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range
```

to optain just the plist data. Finally convert to a `NSString` with:

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```